# Simple lambda function with if statement using python

Tags: python, lambda

I have 1,000 files; the start of each file all look like this:

```
!dataset_description = Analysis of POF D119 mutation. 
!dataset_type = Expression profiling by array
!dataset_pubmed_id = 17318176
!dataset_platform = GPL1322
```

The aim: I want to transform this information into a list so I can make an excel spreadsheet between all the files; i.e. I want the list to look like this:

```
[Analysis_of_POF_D119_mutation,Expression_profiling_by_array,17318176,GPL1322]
```

I have this code (this is just to extract the first variable, "!dataset_description", however, I would subsequently run the code on each variable of interest i.e. !dataset_type, !dataset_pubmed_id, !dataset_platform):

```
OpenDataset = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Dataset = OpenDataset.readlines()
ListOfInformation = []
    formatted_line = lambda x: "_".join(line.strip().split("=")[x].split())
    for line in Dataset:
        if line.startswith("!dataset_description"):
            description = formatted_line(1)
            print description
```

The code works, however, I am now at a stage where I understand python basics, and I want to start coding more "pythonically". I have two questions.

1. It seems silly to use the lambda expression that I am using. "x" in the lambda expression will always be 1, since I will always want what comes after the "=" sign. Therefore x isn't really a "variable", but then I can't have a lambda expression without a variable.

I tried to change the variable to being what the line starts with, which is the true variable, doing something like this:

```
formatted_line = lambda x: "_".join(line.strip().split("=")[1].split()) if line.startswith(x)
```

However, this code returns a syntax error.

Would someone know how to make the above lambda expression work.

2. These files have the potential to be really really big. However, the information that I need is at the start of the file, and all start with the "!" symbol. So it seems silly to read in the whole file, when I'll just need X number of lines at the start of the file, all of which start with "!" (the exact number of lines per file will be variable). Is there a way to read in just the lines starting with "!"; or is it quicker just to use file.readlines().

Comment: Why are you passing `1` always? Pass the `line` instead.

Comment: "then I can't have a lambda expression without a variable" -- sure you can. Just don't put in a variable.

Comment: Lambda "expression"s should produce a value, just like any other expression. In the last `lambda` version, what will be the result of the expression if the line doesn't start with `x`? That is why it produces a Syntax error.

Comment: when the lambda starts getting too long, consider writing a named function, especially since you already assign your lambda to a variable (thus, with a name)

Comment: What λuser said. Using a `lambda` instead of `def` for a named function is generally considered bad style in Python, although that rule is sometimes bent, eg when creating a key function that's used as an arg to `sort` or `sorted` and then immediately re-used as an arg to `itertools.groupby`. Apart from brevity, lambdas have no advantage over full function definitions, but they have several disadvantages. So you should only use them when a simple anonymous function is appropriate.

Comment: BTW, you probably want a `.strip('.')` after `.strip()` to get rid of that trailing period in `!dataset_description`.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can have a lambda expression without an argument.

However, in this case, you should actually pass an argument: the line itself. That is the thing that you're operating on, therefore it should be passed into the function.

Your `if` statement does not work because an inline if in Python must *always* have an else clause. In this case the value in else is the empty string.

So:

```
formatted_line = lambda line: "_".join(line.strip().split("=")[1].split()) if line.startswith(x) else ""
```

If you only want to read values until the lines stop starting with !, you can use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
...
for line in takewhile(lambda line: line.startswith("!"), Dataset):
```

Answer (score 2):

It raises `SyntaxError`, because you're missing an `else` branch. The "expression if" or "inline if" has the syntax: `<value to return when True> if <condition> else <value when False>` You can't use `elif`.

So the code might look like this:

```
formatted_line = lambda x: "_".join(line.strip().split("=")[1].split()) if line.startswith(x) else ""  # You can replace this with `None`.
```